# Remove subfolder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I know that this has been requested a million times but i haven't found an answer.

Basically I want to remove amp from my site but I've a million pages indexed using /amp so if I remove it this will cause a mess.

What I want to do is to redirect all the url like these

```
https://*/amp
```

will go to the same url without amp.

For example an article with this url

```
https://www.tuttosullapostaelettronica.it/blog/come-e-fatta-una-mail/amp
```

will be redirected to the same article without /amp like

```
https://www.tuttosullapostaelettronica.it/blog/come-e-fatta-una-mail
```

This has to be valid for whatever article url that end in /amp that has to be the /amp removed

Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule (.*)/amp$ $1 [R=301]` should do the job.

Comment: @CBroe Without a `RewriteBase` directive being set, that would result in a malformed redirect (missing slash prefix on the _substitution_ string). However, there is also the edge case of the root directory. (And missing `L` flag.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to remove `amp` on requests to the document (first example) and `/amp` on requests to other URLs then you would need a rule like the following using mod_rewrite, near the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?:(.+)/)?amp$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The regex `^(?:(.+)/)?amp$` matches both `amp` and `<something>/amp` and removes `amp` or `/amp` respectively.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.